# Service not starting on button click?

Tags: android, android-service

I've made a service with Android Studio but the service doesn't start when I click the button that I've setup to start the service. Here's my code, I start the service in the getInfo() method:

```
import ...

public class BasicInformation extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText name;
EditText height;
EditText weight;
private String nameStr;
private String heightStr;
private String weightStr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_information);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    boolean firstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isfirstrun", true);

    if (firstRun) {
        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isfirstrun", false).commit();

    } else {
        Intent launchHome = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(launchHome);
    }
}
public void getInfo(View v) {
    // This where I want to start the service 
    Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StepCounterService.class);
    startService(service);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_height);
    weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_weight);

    nameStr = name.getText().toString();
    heightStr = height.getText().toString();
    weightStr = weight.getText().toString();
    Intent goToMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(goToMain);
}

}
```

Here's my StepCounterService:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StepCounterService extends Service {


public StepCounterService() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Step Counting service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}

}
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nina.stepcounter3">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BasicInformation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_basic_information"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".StepCounterService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you also post your service pseudo-code? Maybe your service is already running? Only one instance of Service is created for an application process. And when you call onStart(); again, then only onStartCommand() gets called and new Intent is passed to onStartCommand() method.

Comment: have you defined service in Manifest.xml?

Comment: paste Your tepCounterService.class and Manifest.xml please?

Comment: @pskink nothing

Comment: I'm using that method to start the service @pskink

Comment: @HonorLT I don't the Toast that I've setup to confirm that my service has started,

Comment: @pskink I don't think you can do that, I tried!